# Programmatic control of Nexus S NFC identifier

Tags: android, nfc, nexus-s

When I use an external NFC reader (an ACR122 USB reader) to read my Nexus S's NFC identifier (ie using the mobile as a 'tag'), I get a different result every time.  That makes the phone useless as a personal identifier (unless the sequence is related in a reversible way).  Perhaps that's the point.  Can anyone (a) shed light on this behaviour and (b) tell me how/whether I can override it programatically?  I've search the web and the APIs without success.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK by default NFC is only available on stock Nexus S as P2P and Reader mode. As you can read an identifier I assume you are using P2P mode. In this mode I think that the UID is dynamic, so it changes every time you activate a new communication. I am afraid you won't be able to change that behaviour programatically.